# FTP7.5 - C# IFtpLogProvider incorrect LocalIP/RemoteIP

Tags: c#, ftp, extensibility, windows-server-2008-r2

I am running into the following issue, which applies to Server 2008 R2 only. Microsoft FTP 7.5 has an extensibility interface, IFtpLogProvider, that I am trying to implement to do some custom logging when people connect.

As has been reported [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161937.aspx) and [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/673/how-to-use-managed-code-c-to-create-an-ftp-authentication-provider-with-dynamic-ip-restrictions/), this is a problem in the IFtpLogProvider.Log() method in versions of FTP 7.5 earlier than **the release on August 3, 2009**.

So my question is -- what is the latest release of Server 2008 R2? I can confirm that:

6.1.7600 Build 7600

Has this problem, and I cannot find a way to upgrade to a version of FTP7.5 that does not have this issue. The installers for Server 2008 will not work, unfortunately :(. I am totally stuck unless I can find either an R2 update to address this or I can get confirmation that a newer build of R2 without this issue is available.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by Microsoft in the official IIS forums -- there is no QFE for this, and Server 2008 R2 users are out of luck until the next SP. So if you are developing and wanting to use this interface, DO NOT DO IT if you need RemoteIP information.

Reply from MSFT representative here:

http://forums.iis.net/p/1164391/1932595.aspx#1932595